# GetManifestResourceStream() returning null

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, .net-4.5, embedded-resource

I'm trying to embedd some text files on my application's resouces but when I try to retrieve it using `GetManifestResourceStream()` I get null. I've tried all those name combinations:

- programName.Form1.foo.txt
- programName.foo.txt
- Form1.foo.txt
- programName.Properties.Resources.resources.foo.txt

Some information:

The namespace is `programName` and the class where I'm calling this code from is `Form1` and the file name resouce that I'm trying to retrieve is `foo.txt`.

the code:

```
var resourceName = string.Format("???.{0}", filename);
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
```

The file is available by using `Properties.Resources.foo` but as I get the file name from a string I can't use it.

Comment: If unsure, open your program with il spy, reflector or any other .net decompiler and find there the right resource name.

Comment: @Oscar It seems the text files was placed on `programName.Properties.Resources.resources` shouldn't be on `programName.Form1.resources` instead of? on the last one there are stuff like the application's icon and background. I guess that's why I''m getting null

Comment: It depends of how you created the resource file. Try with the value obtained from decompilation.

Comment: I created/added them by Project -> Properties -> Resources -> Add Existing file. Is this the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your file's build action is "Embedded Resource".
If you file is in a folder you must include the folder's name.

For example if I create a folder "xx" in my WindowsFormsApplication1 project and add a file "dictionary.txt" ,the name will be
**WindowsFormsApplication1.xx.dictionary.txt**

In any case just use this to see all your resources

```
var files = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Comment: Where do I check if te build action value?

Comment: I've checked `GetManifestResourceNames()` and it doesn't contains the files I've added I guess that's the way I added  it: Project -> Properties -> Resources -> Add Existing file.

Comment: Found this property! Is needed to open the file first. I was looking for it at the resouce editor. Switch from "none" to "Embedded Resource" and it worked